# ng-bootstrap accordion click not firing in IE

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

**I am trying to implement ng-bootstrap accordion in my application**

```js
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="config-panel-one">
          <div *ngFor="let parent of parentsInfo;let j = index">
            <ngb-panel>
              <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                <div role="button" (click)="collapseExpand(parent)">
                    {{parent.folderName}}
                  <span class="fa fa-chevron-right" [ngClass]="{'fa-chevron-down':parent.isExpand, 'fa-chevron-right':!parent.isExpand}"></span>
               </div>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
               {{parent.filename}}
              </ng-template>
            </ngb-panel><br>
          </div>
        </ngb-accordion>
```

**I am just trying to set the chevron based on the expand vs collapse.The click function collapseExpand(parent) sets the flag "isExpand"**

[image]

**The above functionality is working fine in chrome browser but its not working in IE. The collapseExpand function is not getting fired in Internet Explorer. can any one let me know how to fix it.**

I am using   "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0", angular 7

Comment: Can you post your full code in ts? Can't see the problem right now.

Comment: could u create a sample post in the stackblitz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem : Primarily ngb-accordian has a default button in it, now from your code when it is(ngb-accordian) seeing the div under the template it is just ignoring it and proceeding forward.

Solution: We can work other way around using the button instead of div like below:

```
 <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                <button class="btn btn-link"  (click)="collapseExpand(parent)">
                    {{parent.folderName}}
                  <span class="fa fa-chevron-right" [ngClass]="{'fa-chevron-down':parent.isExpand, 'fa-chevron-right':!parent.isExpand}"></span>
               </button>
              </ng-template>
```

All the best.